# Hiding a TextBox value

Tags: ms-access, vba

This is what I thought of.

```
Private Sub TextBox_Enter()
     TextBox.value.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: So what do you want to achieve? And what does not work? What is your question? When you want to hide a textbox you can simply change the `Visible` attribute to `False`

Comment: You cannot hide control that you have focus on. And you have if you typed value into it.

Comment: I want to hide text soon as I enter a value is entered in it. The current value displayed in the Textbox is 0. The  but the problem is, when users update the database, instead of adding say 1, they end up adding 10.

Comment: Use `TextBox.value = ""` to clear the textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the value again, store it temporarily in the control's `Tag` property and restore on `Exit`.

```
Private Sub TextBox_Enter()
     With TextBox
        .Tag = .Value
        .Value = Null
    End With
End Sub
```

To restore it if the value is Null:

```
Private Sub TextBox_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
     With TextBox
        If IsNull(.Value) Then .Value = .Tag
    End With
End Sub
```